# How to use the value of variable as a key in a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm continuing learning python and I want to use the value of a variable as a key in a dictionary, and the input of the user as the value of that key, but what I'm doing is doing the opposite.

```
def scan_option(option_type):
    option_dict={}
    elected_type = option_type + '_option'
    option_dict.update(elected_type= raw_input("Enter the {} Option: ".format(option_type)))

    return option_dict

print scan_option("Hardrive")
```

In case user answered 8:
The output is: `{'elected_type': '8'}`
and I want it to be: `{'Hardrive_option': '8'}`

What do I need to change in the code to do that?

Comment: `option_dict[elected_type] = raw_input("Enter the {} Option: ".format(option_type))`

Comment: Awesome, I did not realize that it was as simple as that.
I think I used wrong the update of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update` takes a dictionary as its argument.  The stuff you fed it was a symbol and a string; it converts that to a dictionary and then does the update.

The syntax you need here is a simple dictionary assignment:

```
option_dict[elected_type] = raw_input(...)
```

You might try simpler commands when you first write your code.  Once those work properly, *then* you can go for the one-line, compound commands.